# Is it possible to log the class and object that is sending a message to another method?

Tags: objective-c, xcode

I am trying to find out which one of my objects is sending a release message and how many times. I need a way to print out in the debugger the object that is sending the message. Is this possible to do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can always use:

`NSLog( @"[%@ %@] - %d -> Doing something", [self class], NSStringFromSelector(_cmd), __LINE__ );`

But, if you trying to figure out if an object is being deallocated before you expected, a better method would be enable `NSZombie`. [This SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5387006/620197) has very good instructions on how to enable `NSZombie`, and [this](http://www.markj.net/iphone-memory-debug-nszombie/) should help to use `NSZombie` with Instruments.

Comment: What if I need to do this in a C funtion.

Comment: @Stephen That is different, you mentioned objects and methods. I'll see if I can find a solution for that.

Comment: @Stephen I think `NSLog( @"%s" __func__)` will do it.

Comment: Try something like : `NSLog( @" - %s %s() %d -> Doing something", __FILE__, __FUNCTION__, __LINE__ );`